# Наполнить переменные данными в Golang

Tags: golang, переменные, обновление

Написали функцию для чтения данных из порта. Как правильно наполнить переменные данными?

```
func getSpeed(name string) {

    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive(name, 1024, true, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer handle.Close()


    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {

        rxBytes := packet.Metadata().CaptureInfo.Length
        txBytes := packet.Metadata().CaptureInfo.Length
    
        fmt.Printf("RX Bytes: %d \t TX Bytes: %d \n", rxBytes, txBytes)
    }


  iface := &model.Iface{
    Name:  "",
    TxSec: "",
    RxSec: "",
    Tx:    "",
    Rx:    "",
  }

}
```

Comment: вообще непонятно что это за модель и что значит RxSec, а Rx является строкой, что тоже непонятно

Comment: укажите как получать значения для полей TxSec и RxSec и вообще что это атакое

Comment: Rx это данные в байтах

Comment: RxSec это отправка байт в секундах

Comment: Нужно в переменных накапливать данные в байтах и посчитать  разницу между ними в секундах, т.о. измерять скорость на интерфейсе